# Reallocated Sectors count above 300, Should i replace the hardisk

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, bsod

I have a toshiba laptop and facing many issues lately. I installed Crystaldiskinfo which is a S.M.A.R.T information reader and found out the drive status to be in **Caution** state.

When i hover over the Caution status it shows 341 reallocated sectors count and 99 pending sector count. These figures are increasing.

Also the Raw values figure for Reallocated Sectors count is 155.

[image]

Should i replace the hardisk?

Comment: The “Raw Values” column has hex numbers. 0x155 is 341.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should. I'd actually suggest avoiding using the disk further except to back up.

Modern disks are *really* good at handling small amounts of damage - reallocated sectors tend to mean "a sector was bad but we've managed to get the data elsewhere"

That said "it depends", A 320gb disk is *usually* older, and well, you're hitting the point where preventive replacement is a good idea. On the other hand, if you're mainly using the disk for *transient* data of *no real importance*, meh, just use it till it fails.

This looks like a system disk and if you value your data, backing up and replacing it *posthaste* is what you should do.

Comment: Agreed; also a HDTune read test could detect eventual bad sectors that yet have not been reallocated.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have ordered a new one. Your answer made the decision easier.